# save! method for referenced attributes in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, overriding, mongoid, setter

I use Rails 3.0.6 with mongoID 2.0.2. Recently I encountered an issue with save! method when overriding setter (I am trying to create my own nested attributes).

So here is the model:

```
class FeedItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :audio_refs

  def audio_refs=(attributes_array, binding)

    attributes_array.each do |attributes|
      if attributes[:audio_track][:id]
        self.audio_refs.build(:audio_track => AudioTrack.find(attributes[:audio_track][:id]))
      elsif attributes[:audio_track][:file]
        self.audio_refs.build(:audio_track => AudioTrack.new(:user_id => attributes[:audio_track][:user_id], :file => attributes[:audio_track][:file]))
      end
    end

    if !binding
      self.save!
    end
  end
```

AudioRef model (which is just buffer between audio_tracks and feed_items) is:

```
class AudioRef
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :feed_item
  belongs_to :audio_track

end
```

And AudioTrack:

```
class AudioTrack
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :audio_refs
  mount_uploader :file, AudioUploader
end
```

So here is the spec for the FeedItem model which doesn`t work:

```
  it "Should create audio_track and add audio_ref" do
      @audio_track = Fabricate(:audio_track, :user_id => @author.id, :file => File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/stuff/test.mp3"))
      @feed_item= FeedItem.new(
        :user => @author,
        :message => {:body => Faker::Lorem.sentence(4)},
        :audio_refs => [
            {:audio_track => {:id => @audio_track.id}},
            {:audio_track => {:user_id => @author.id, :file => File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/stuff/test.mp3")}}
        ]
      )
      @feed_item.save!          
      @feed_item.reload
      @feed_item.audio_refs.length.should be(2)
  end
```

As you can see, the reason I am overriding audio_refs= method is that FeedItem can be created from existing AudioTracks (when there is params[:audio_track][:id]) or from uploaded file (params[:audio_track][:file]).

The problem is that @feed_item.audio_refs.length == 0 when I run this spec, i.e. audio_refs are not saved. Could you please help me with that?

Some investigation:

1) binding param is "true" by default (this means we are in building mode)

Comment: I recommend you accept answers on your previous 6 questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem but I didnt understand why save method doesnt work and didn`t make my code work. So first of all let me describe my investigations about the problem. After audio_refs= is called an array of audio_refs is created BUT in any audio_ref is no feed_item_id. Probably it is because the feed_item is not saved by the moment.

So the solution is quite simple - Virtual Attributes. To understand them watch [corresponding railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes)

So my solution is to create audio_refs by means of callback "after_save"

I slightly changed my models:

In FeedItem.rb I added

```
attr_writer :audio_tracks #feed_item operates with audio_tracks array
after_save :assign_audio #method to be called on callback

def assign_audio
    if @audio_tracks
      @audio_tracks.each do |attributes|
        if attributes[:id]
          self.audio_refs << AudioRef.new(:audio_track => AudioTrack.find(attributes[:id]))
        elsif attributes[:file]
          self.audio_refs << AudioRef.new(:audio_track => AudioTrack.new(:user_id => attributes[:user_id], :file => attributes[:file]))
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And the spec is now:

```
it "Should create audio_track and add audio_ref" do
      @audio_track = Fabricate(:audio_track, :user_id => @author.id, :file => File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/stuff/test.mp3"))
      @feed_item= FeedItem.new(
        :user => @author,
        :message => {:body => Faker::Lorem.sentence(4)},
        :audio_tracks => [
            {:id => @audio_track.id},
            {:user_id => @author.id, :file => File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/stuff/test.mp3")}
        ]
      )
      @feed_item.save!          
      @feed_item.reload
      @feed_item.audio_refs.length.should be(2)
  end
```

And it works fine!!! Good luck with your coding)

Answer (score 0):

Check that `audio_refs=()` is actually being called, by adding debug output of some kind.  My feeling is that your `FeedItem.new()` call doesn't use the `audio_refs=()` setter.

Here's the source code of the `ActiveRecord::Base#initialize` method, taken from [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 1396
def initialize(attributes = nil)
  @attributes = attributes_from_column_definition
  @attributes_cache = {}
  @new_record = true
  @readonly = false
  @destroyed = false
  @marked_for_destruction = false
  @previously_changed = {}
  @changed_attributes = {}

  ensure_proper_type

  populate_with_current_scope_attributes
  self.attributes = attributes unless attributes.nil?

  result = yield self if block_given?
  _run_initialize_callbacks
  result
end
```

I don't currently have an environment to test this, but it looks like it's setting the `attributes` hash directly without going through each attribute's setter.  If that's the case, you'll need to call your setter manually.

Actually, I think the fact you're not getting an exception for the number of arguments (`binding` not set) proves that your setter isn't being called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Oliver! I check what you said and this setter method is called and binding is true by default. I raise self.audio_refs and get a proper array, that means that audio_refs() is actually called. But the problem is that it doesn`t save audio_refs.